# Где расположить вложенный класс в C#?

Tags: c#, классы

Для каждого класса нужно создавать отдельный файл. А что со вложенными классами? Нужно ли для них создавать отдельный файл (и можно ли вообще так сделать?) или их можно со спокойной душой оставлять в основном классе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать частичные (partial) классы.

В одном файле внешний класс:

```
partial class Outer
{
    // properties, fields, constructors, methods
}
```

В другом файле внутренний класс:

```
partial class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Скажу вам по секрету - можно вообще весь проект писать в одном файле и ничего страшного не случится :D Кроме инфаркта у архитектора приложения, конечно же)

Куда именно и что класть целиком зависит от кодстандарта и вашего представления о прекрасном :)

Comment: писал более развернутый ответ но с тем же смыслом но забыл нажать ответить(((